# Can someone tell what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am a beginner and just can't figure out what am I doing wrong in this code. The result ends in a infinite loop (I think), that prints nothing. I intentionally left function speak() non-virtual and I know I'll only get Animal's data printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_speak;

public:
    Animal(string name, string speak = "???"): m_name(name), m_speak(speak){}
    string speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_speak;}
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_dspeak;

public:
    Dog(string name, string speak = "Woof!"): Animal(name), m_dspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_dspeak;}
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_cspeak;

public:

    Cat(string name, string speak = "Meow!"): Animal(name), m_cspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_cspeak;}
};

int main()
{
    Cat Fred("Fred");
    Dog Stuffy("Stuffy");

    Animal *ptr = &Fred;
    cout << ptr->speak() << endl;

    Animal *ptr2 = &Stuffy;
    cout << ptr2->speak() << endl;
}
```

Can someone help? I may did a very silly mistake here. Please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The compiler can give you some [handy warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83f81f779492851).

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal Return a string or make the return type `void`.

Comment: You are outputting the name instead of returning it.

Comment: Please provide a meaningful title, instead of one that could apply to 99.9% of the millions of questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Change your two implementations of `speak()` to be something like this:

```
string speak(){ return m_name + " speaks " + m_speak; }
```

Currently, your `speak` methods don't have a return statement, so the return value is undefined, which could cause weird problems.

Comment: For the sake of learning, Why am I down voted twice and you are voted up when we're doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have made two major mistakes.

1. In the classes Animal, Dog and Cat you have three speak functions. But you declared them as string type functions. But the only output some text but does not return anything. You have to change them to void. Or you can return the text instead of outputing it.
2. In the main function you have written `cout << ptr->speak() << endl;` to output the text. But your speak function does not return any string to output. It outputs the text itself. So, you have to write     `ptr->speak();` to output the speech of the animal. You don't need **cout** there.

I have given two sample codes below. You can choose either of them. Both works just fine.

**Sample #1: using void (no cout in main)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_speak;

public:
    Animal(string name, string speak = "???"): m_name(name), m_speak(speak){}
    void speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_speak;}
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_dspeak;

public:
    Dog(string name, string speak = "Woof!"): Animal(name), m_dspeak(speak){}
    void speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_dspeak;}
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_cspeak;

public:

    Cat(string name, string speak = "Meow!"): Animal(name), m_cspeak(speak){}
    void speak(){cout << m_name << " speaks " << m_cspeak;}
};

int main()
{
    Cat Fred("Fred");
    Dog Stuffy("Stuffy");

    Animal *ptr = &Fred;
    ptr->speak();

    Animal *ptr2 = &Stuffy;
    ptr2->speak();
}
```

**Sample #2: using return in functions and cout in main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_speak;

public:
    Animal(string name, string speak = "???"): m_name(name), m_speak(speak){}
    string speak(){return m_name + " speaks " + m_speak;}

};

class Dog: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_dspeak;

public:
    Dog(string name, string speak = "Woof!"): Animal(name), m_dspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){ return m_name + " " + m_speak;}
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_cspeak;

public:

    Cat(string name, string speak = "Meow!"): Animal(name), m_cspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){ return m_name + " speaks " + m_cspeak;}
};

int main()
{
    Cat Fred("Fred");
    Dog Stuffy("Stuffy");

    Animal *ptr = &Fred;
    cout << ptr->speak() << endl;

    Animal *ptr2 = &Stuffy;
    cout << ptr2->speak() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I am sorry I misunderstood your question. I edited the answer.

You do not need to cout in the function. You would do that in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
protected:
    string m_name;
    string m_speak;

public:
    Animal(string name, string speak = "???"): m_name(name), m_speak(speak){}
    string speak(){return m_name + " speaks " + m_speak;}

};

class Dog: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_dspeak;

public:
    Dog(string name, string speak = "Woof!"): Animal(name), m_dspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){ return m_name + " " + m_speak;}
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
private:
    string m_cspeak;

public:

    Cat(string name, string speak = "Meow!"): Animal(name), m_cspeak(speak){}
    string speak(){ return m_name + " speaks " + m_cspeak;}
};

int main()
{
    Cat Fred("Fred");
    Dog Stuffy("Stuffy");

    Animal *ptr = &Fred;
    cout << ptr->speak() << endl;

    Animal *ptr2 = &Stuffy;
    cout << ptr2->speak() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. He was using cout in the function instead of return. My answer now has an output of Fred speaks ???
Stuffy speaks ???

Comment: Maybe your downvotes happened before the edit, when you still had `return 0;` inside a function that is supposed to return a string?  If not, then I don't know why someone would downvote you; they should leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: Ok cool I dont care about the votes. I just didn't want to leave information up that was not accurate. Thanks man. If you do notice something please let me know.